# HTML, Javascript - Split word that's wider than iFrame instead of generating scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, designmode, execcommand

I'm using the ExecCommand for making a very basic WYSIWYG editor as a future project will require me to make one (therefore please don't tell me to for something like CKEditor or tinyMCE). It all works fine when used normally. But if you enter a word that is wider than the iFrame the word doesn't split. Instead a scrollbar is just added to the iFrame. Here is a video showing my problem: https://vimeo.com/42699618
So I'm wondering what the easiest way to prevent this is?

And here is the code:

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
    textArea.document.designMode = 'On'; 

    $("#bold").click(makeBold);
    $("#italic").click(makeItalic);

    function makeBold() {
        textArea.document.execCommand('bold', true, null);
        $("#textArea").focus();
    }
    function makeItalic() {
        textArea.document.execCommand('italic', false, null);
        $("#textArea").focus();
    }
});
</script>
<body>

    <iframe id="textArea" style="width: 700px; height:400px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Do you want the auto breaking element to start from the last word and fit to what remains before going to a new line? Or do you want to start these auto break elements on their own line? Or is there another behavior you are expecting?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure if I understand you as my English isn't the very best. But I want the auto break to work like in tinyMCE for example. Like this(video): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9pxUtyuYnM&feature=youtu.be

Comment: When you leave a comment in this box, your "word" will go to a new line once it exceeds the width of the line before wrapping. When it exceeds the width of the box, it then auto breaks the word onto a second line.

do you want the auto breaking word to stay on the first line (not what this comment system does), or move to a new line (like this comment system does)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially your existing system takes care of the first part, putting the word on a new line. You picked the easier version :)

When you render your word, you need to split the string into a number of strings based on the length of the word, and the width of your field.

Make sure you are only splitting the word in the view, and not the word in the data!
If the user resizes the view, you wouldn't want to try and put the data back together again :p

Steps:
Every time you render, each word is checked to see if it exceeds the width of the view, if it does, split it, render the pieces in order, and continue.

Comment: Thank you! Though I'm not sure I know how to do that practically. Can you give me a code example?

Comment: Calculating word glyphs for width based on various layouts and languages is no small task. You might be able to get away with just doing character counts with a little whitespace padding to prevent wrapping, but font variations can be troublesome. Is this an English only text system?

Comment: Ah, I see your point. Haven't been working much with this kind of stuff earlier. I've mostly been working with PHP and nothing with real-time text processing.  But I understand what needs to be done, thank you!
No, it will mainly be used for Swedish.